# Reverse direction of pointers in doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a circular doubly linked list and I want to change the direction of all the `next` and `prev` pointers. I can't really figure out what the source of the error is.  When I print the reversed list, it gets the first two numbers correct but past that point the links list stops printing.

```
struct Link
{
    TYPE value;
    struct Link * next;
    struct Link * prev;
};

struct CircularList
{
    int size;
    struct Link* sentinel;
};

static void init(struct CircularList* list)
{
    list->sentinel = (struct Link *) malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    list->sentinel->next = list->sentinel;
    list->sentinel->prev = list->sentinel;
    list->size = 0;
}

struct CircularList* circularListCreate()
{
    struct CircularList* list = malloc(sizeof(struct CircularList));
    init(list);
    return list;
}

void circularListAddFront(struct CircularList* list, TYPE value)
{
    struct Link *newLink = (struct Link *) malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    newLink->value = value;
    newLink->next = list->sentinel->next;
    newLink->prev = list->sentinel;
    list->sentinel->next = newLink;
    if(circularListIsEmpty(list)) {
        list->sentinel->prev = newLink;
    }
    list->size++;
}

void circularListRemoveFront(struct CircularList* list)
{
    struct Link *temp = list->sentinel->next;
    temp->next->prev = list->sentinel;
    list->sentinel->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    list->size--;
}

void circularListRemoveBack(struct CircularList* list)
{
    struct Link *temp = list->sentinel->prev;
    temp->prev->next = list->sentinel;
    list->sentinel->prev = temp->prev;
    free(temp);
    list->size--;
}

void circularListReverse(struct CircularList* list)
{
    struct Link *link = list->sentinel->next;
    while(link != list->sentinel) {
        struct Link *nextTemp = link->next;
        struct Link *prevTemp = link->prev;
        link->prev = link->next;
        link->next = prevTemp;
        link = nextTemp;
    }
    struct Link *temp = list->sentinel->next;
    list->sentinel->next = list->sentinel->prev;
    list->sentinel->prev = temp;
}
```

If I run the following to test this I get the output `5 4 1 2 2 1` and then terminates with no errors.

```
struct CircularList *deque = circularListCreate();
circularListAddBack(deque, 1);
circularListAddBack(deque, 2);
circularListAddBack(deque, 3);
circularListAddFront(deque, 4);
circularListAddFront(deque, 5);
circularListAddFront(deque, 6);
circularListRemoveFront(deque);
circularListRemoveBack(deque);
circularListPrint(deque);
circularListReverse(deque);
circularListPrint(deque);
```

Comment: `sentinel`? I could do that for this list: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/list-c/ and post an answer, hoping that you will grasp the idea and apply it to your double list.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node

Comment: Please add definitions of the used structures, along with an example of given input, expected output and actual output. Ideally this would be a minimal compiling example code.

Comment: @DanielJour Just added in all the relevant code, and the test cases/output.

Comment: Could you also include `circularListRemoveFront()` and `circularListRemoveBack()`. If the output from your print function is "5 4 3 2 1", then you likely have a bug in `circularListRemoveFront()`. If I'm reading your test case correctly, `1` should not appear in the output since the first thing you do is remove it, no?

Comment: @scootermefecit Added those in for you.

Comment: Side note: Do not cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: Another side note: Your remove functions should make sure not to remove the sentinel.

Comment: Expected output would be `5 4 1 2 2 1 4 5`, right? (The second half being the output after reversing)

Comment: @DanielJour Yes, that should be the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in your `circularListAddFront` function, and (though not shown) probably also in `circularListAddBack`:

Assume this state of the list:

```
p+SENTINEL+n
|    A     |
-----|------
```

Now, let's say you add `42` to the front. You first allocate a new node and set its value and pointers. Also you set the `sentinel` next pointer:

```
struct Link *newLink = (struct Link *) malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
newLink->value = value;
newLink->next = list->sentinel->next;
newLink->prev = list->sentinel;
list->sentinel->next = newLink;
```

This leads to the following state:

```
p+SENTINEL+n
|    A     |
-----|     |
     |     |
------     |
|    |     |
p+42+n     |
   A       |
   |       |
   ---------
```

Which is not fine, because the `prev` pointer of the sentinel still points to itself. You fix that directly after that:

```
if(circularListIsEmpty(list)) {
    list->sentinel->prev = newLink;
}
list->size++;
```

This gives the desired result:

```
  p+SENTINEL+n
--|    A     |
|      |     |
| ------     |
| |    |     |
| p+42+n     |
|    A       |
|    |       |
--------------
```

This is fine. Now let's add a `21` to the glorious list:

```
----------
|        |
|        V
|   p+SENTINEL+n
| --|    A     |
| |      |     |
| | ------     |
| | |    |     |
| | p+42+n     |
| |    A       |
| |    |       |
| -----|       |
|      |       |
| p+21+n       |
--|  A         |
     |         |
     -----------
```

That's the state right before that `if`, and it has the same issue as before: There's one `prev` pointer wrong, this time it's not sentinels but the one of node `42`: It should point to its previous node, which is now `21`, and not to the sentinel.

Since the `if` is not taken, the sate remains. You don't notice it until reversing the list because you don't use the `prev` pointers until then.

To fix that, get rid of the `if` and correct the logic unconditionally:

When you insert a new node to the front ("after the sentinel"), then you need to change the `prev` pointer of the node that was at the front before and point it to the new node:

```
newLink->next = list->sentinel->next;
newLink->prev = list->sentinel;
list->sentinel->next->prev = newLink; // ADDITION
list->sentinel->next = newLink;
```

The code for reversing the list seems fine, though. And for now, I'm done with "line art ASCII graphics" :D